# Finding the Generating function for Pentagonal Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, polygons

There is a problem on this site that solves this problem for triangular numbers... However, I wasn't able to apply the same reasonaning for pentagonal numbers.

In general the $kth$ pentagonal number is given by $a_k=(3k^2-k)/2$. Now, I am meant to find the generating function:

$f(x)=a_o+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$, Where the coefficients are the pentagonal numbers.

In the case of the triangular numbers, the solution involved expanding

$1/(1-x)=\sum x^k$ and using some manipulations to get this into the closed form needed. Any advice would be much appreciated. On and ending note, I am wondering if anyone has any resources to direct me to for finding generating functions. The class I am taking is using simple recurrences and sequences, so nothing too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^{i}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2 } \\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^2x^{i}=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3 } \\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3i^2-i)}{2}x^{i}=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^2x^{i}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^{i}=\frac{2x^2+x}{(1-x)^3 } \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ok, thanks. Question: How did you come up with the first formula, and what made you decide to use it ?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i+1}=\frac{x}{(1-x) } \\
\end{eqnarray*} differentiate this ... & you will get the first formula. Differentiate again ... do a little algebra & you will get the second formula.